# RL circuit graph problem

Tags: homework

An inductor and a resistor are connected in series. I have to find the resistance R, inductance L, voltage across the inductor V and initial flux linkage from the graphs (c) and (d).

[image]

There was no additional information given but as far as I know these graph are showing the state of a circuit after a switch was turned on. After doing some research I found that these graphs below resembled the ones given in the problem, so I tried to do the calculations based on them.

[image]

The results that I got were:

L/R=0.1

L=0.1R

E/R=4

E=4R

Then I assumed E=50 V and got R=12.5 ohms, L=1.25 H. However, not one of these answers was correct.
Am I misunderstanding something? I've noticed that in graph (c) the curve starts from 1 A. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Graph (c) implies a series resistor **and** a parallel resistor.

Comment: How is there also a parallel resistor?

Comment: I can't tell you how; I'm just saying that the graph (c) starting at 1 amp has to mean a parallel resistive path.

Comment: The final voltage in Graph (d) is greater than zero implying a resistor voltage. This means a series circuit. @Andyaka

Comment: The two graphs don't make sense. If graph d is the inductor voltage then it should go to zero. But the question asks to find the inductor voltage. If graph d is the resistor voltage then it should be increasing if in series, so Andy's comment makes sense. they look as in parallel.

Comment: Yes, a series resistor and a resistor in parallel with L.